# How do I integrate client modifications to compiled CSS and JS

Tags: javascript, build, sass, gulp

I currently use Gulp to compile SASS -> CSS and concat to combine my JS modules.

The end compiled code is then delivered to a user and they drop into their server.

The catch is the user makes changes to said code as needed, and then when I have to make an update, the codebases our of sync as they touched have the compiled code. They send their updated package back to me, and then I usually work from their compiled code, not ideal. The user has no knowledge of SASS or Gulp so asking them to work in my way is out of the question.

Does anyone know of a way to take their modifications and re-create my modules and SCSS? I was thinking of setting markers in the compilation, but this has been a pain point of development for me.

Comment: What kinds of client changes are we talking?

Comment: You should restructure the code to be extensible so they do not have to modify the core code to add their own functionality to it. How to do that is beyond the scope of a SO question

Comment: The changes vary, sometimes they integrate third party services into the compiled app.js for example. Other times it's changes to CSS here and there.